# Navigation bar title view missing in iOS11

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11

I'm working on a project in swift for `iPad`.
Have placed an image view in Navigation bar title view from story board.
The title view is displaying as expected in `iOS 10` and below.
The same project when i run in **iOS 11 simulators and the physical devices Navigation bar is not showing the title view**, any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: any code on how you did this would be appreciated.

Comment: No Code to add title view, That was added from Storyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 11 Navigation TitleView misplaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578752/ios-11-navigation-titleview-misplaced)

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom view and override below method in the custom title view class to update view frame size at runtime.

*Obj-C*

```
-(CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    [super intrinsicContentSize];
    return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize;
}
```

*Swift*

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize
}
```

Check and let me know is it working for you or not ?

Comment: Just debug with hierarchy view option and you come to know frame size of custom titleView is zero in ios 11 alone. To update frame size at runtime you need to call this method.

Comment: Oh is it? does this code shows any impact on the existing behavior for iOS 10 and below? or it's specific to iOS 11 only?

Comment: I hope, No impact on existing behavior of iOS 10 and below. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```
let widthConstraint = view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
let heightConstraint = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:height)
widthConstraint.isActive = true
heightConstraint.isActive = true
```

`view` is the view that you use as a custom title view. And `width` and `height` is the size that you want to use. You can use:

```
let width = view.frame.width
let height = view.frame.height
```