# NavigationBar.titleView is not displayed in iOS 11

Tags: swift, ios11

I see it in debug view hierarchy but don't in simulator/device. What is the problem? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: can you post a zoomed out picture? Are you sure you have a navigationBar when your view loads?

Comment: The alpha value may be 0. All views in the view hierarchy debugger are displayed with a value of 1.0 to allow you to see them. You can verify this by selecting the view and checking the alpha property in the inspector on the right.

Comment: Confirm the problem, also facing it after updating the project to Swift 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation bar title view missing in iOS11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485827/navigation-bar-title-view-missing-in-ios11)